# First Column Not Imported as Index Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have the following csv file:

[image]

I created it by using the pandas export option:

```
database.to_csv('database.csv')
```

But when I import it using:

```
database = pd.read_csv("database.csv")
```

I get:

[image]

As you can see the first column was not automatically assigned as the index.

**Why is that ? ... and how can I fix it ?**

Comment: [`read_csv` takes an `index_col` argument](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).  Set that to `0`.  As always, the documentation should be the first place you look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
database = pd.read_csv("database.csv", index_col=0)
```